# How to write a dynamic macro for Windows?

Tags: windows, automation, macros

I'm trying to write my own Windows Macro, but a lot of the content online seems to skew towards VBA and Excel, or more static "type this and be done" or "do this, then do this later" macros. I am looking for a way to write more programmatic macros to automate tedious tasks that contain dynamic inputs.

I have read into [this article on arrays in VBA for Excel which ranges as Dynamic input](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291069/visual-basic-macro-examples-for-working-with-arrays) but that is not what I am after.

What I am after is a way to record a macro, but pick apart a piece inside of it (i.e. look at the code that was written to perform it) and insert tiny actions in the middle of it, such as pulling from an array to use instead of using the performed keypresses, and iterating continuously till the array is empty.

Example (not related to project):

1. I open a new tab (ctrl+t)
2. I type in a random web address (www.example.com)
3. I click on a piece of the page at random

I'd want to pull apart that macro to insert a different address multiple times at stage 2, so I would open as many tabs as the array required to be completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you recorded the following macro to pull company data.

```
    Sub Macro3()
    '
    ' Macro3 Macro
    '

    '
        Range("A5").Select
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "URL;https://www.google.com/search?q=NYSE:GE&tbm=fin&gws_rd=ssl#gws_rd=ssl&scso=_EzKKXMOFH8jKswXW2pigDQ2:0&spf=1552560659066&wptab=COMPANY" _
            , Destination:=Range("$A$5"))
            .CommandType = 0
            .Name = "0&spf=1552560659066&wptab=COMPANY_1"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebTables = "4"
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    End Sub
```

Here's how you might put it in a loop. CommandType was throwing an error and is not needed, so it had to be removed.

```
    Sub GetCompanyData()
    Dim companies(1 To 3) As String

    i = 1
    companies(i) = "F": i = i + 1
    companies(i) = "CAT": i = i + 1
    companies(i) = "GE": i = i + 1

    For i = 1 To UBound(companies)

        LastUSedRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        NextInsertAddr = Cells(LastUSedRow + 1, 1).Address
        Range(NextInsertAddr) = "Company: " + companies(i)
        NextInsertAddr = Cells(LastUSedRow + 2, 1).Address
        URLToPull = "URL;https://www.google.com/search?q=NYSE:" + companies(i) + "&tbm=fin&gws_rd=ssl#gws_rd=ssl&scso=_EzKKXMOFH8jKswXW2pigDQ2:0&spf=1552560659066&wptab=COMPANY"
    '
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=URLToPull _
            , Destination:=Range(NextInsertAddr))
      '      .CommandType = 0
            .Name = "0&spf=1552560659066&wptab=COMPANY"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebTables = "4"
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    Next i


    End Sub
```